# FullCalendar - How can I increase space between timline hours?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using this basic example http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/demos/theme.html

Wanted to increase size between timeline hours, so if I have 20min event then title dont show up fully

[image: screenshot]

any suggestions ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up increasing width of this class

`.fc-timeline .fc-head .fc-cell-content .fc-cell-text {width: 400px;}`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything with the default calendar settings. If an event is less than the 30-minute slot, it will occupy only a part of this slot.

[image]